# How to set the type of a generic enum in Dart

Tags: dart, generics, enums

Given the enum below:

```dart
enum Animal<T> {
  cow,
  goat;
}
```

How do I set the type?

If I do this:

```dart
void main() {
  final animal = Animal.cow;
}
```

Dart infers the type of `animal` to be `Animal<dynamic>`. However, I'm not able to set the type with any of the following ways:

```dart
// The static member 'cow' can't be accessed on a class instantiation.
final animal = Animal<int>.cow;

// `animal` is inferred to be `dynamic`, not `Animal<int>`.
final animal = Animal.cow<int>;
```

Of course, I'm not using the type anywhere, but this is the simplest example I can think of to demonstrate my question. How would I set the type to `int`?

Comment: Out of curiosity: what is your use case for generic `enum`s?

Comment: @jamesdlin, I'm teaching enhanced enums to other people so at this point I'm exploring what's possible. To be honest, I haven't found any serious use case for generic enums, so if you know of any I'd love to hear more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enum values must be constant so the generic needs to be specified as part of initializing the enum values inside the enum definition.

So something like this:

```dart
enum Animal<T> {
  cow<String>(),
  goat<int>();
}

void main() {
  print(Animal.cow.runtimeType); // Animal<String>
  print(Animal.goat.runtimeType); // Animal<int>
}
```

Comment: Ah, so the generic type is tied to the enum values. I was thinking I could maybe use it with some method. Reading your answer it finally clicked for me. Each enum value is one instance of the Enum class.